# How to write Html in asp.net core web api , Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to send a message through email in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API.

```
public void SendMail(string password, string to)
{
    var host = _config.GetSection("Email:HOST").Value;
    var port = _config.GetSection("Email:PORT").Value;
    var fromEmail = _config.GetSection("Email:Credentials:Username").Value;
    var passwordOfFromEmail = _config.GetSection("Email:Credentials:Password").Value;
    var toEmail = to;

    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail))
    {
        mm.Subject = "Your Secret Password";
        // mm.Body = "Your Secret Password is " + password;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

        mm.Body = $"<p>Your Secret Password is " + password + "</b> To unsubscribe your account, <form method=\"post\" action=\"http://localhost:5000/api/newsletter-subscription/public/unsubscribe\" class=\"inline\">  <input name=\"email\" value="toEmail"> <button type = \"submit\" name = \"submit_param\"  value ="toEmail" class=\"link-button\"> Click Here   </button> </form>.</p>";

        // removed rest
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement [Application]
>
> ; expected [Application] at `value="toEmail"`

Comment: ` name=\"email\" value="toEmail"` spot the difference ... did you mean to escape the quotes? Or append the strings together? Note that you should ensure the value is escaped for html / attributes. What if the password contained '<br/>' ?

Comment: I want to insert the dynamic value to `value="here"`

Comment: Its a typo mistake. Please replace `value="toEmail"` with `value=" + toEmail + "`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only use "{toEmail}" to insert email values

```
mm.Body = $"<p>Your Secret Password is { password }</b> To unsubscribe your account,
 <form method=\"post\" action=\"http://localhost:5000/api/newsletter-subscription/public/unsubscribe\" class=\"inline\">  
<input name=\"email\" value=\"{toEmail}\"> <button type = \"submit\" name = \"submit_param\"  
value = \"{toEmail}\" class=\"link-button\"> Click Here   </button> </form>.</p>";
```

Comment: { password } this is works, but value="{toEmail}" this does not work

Comment: @hanushi I updated my answer, try again. You have to put evertything in one line